# Macro for copying data in the next available cell to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macro and trying to set up a macro which updates a range of data into another spreadsheet.
In Week 1, I need to copy it into the master summary sheet in column B (Range B2:B19)
In week 2 , I need it to copy into master summary sheet in Column C (Range C2:C19) and not overnight the previous week.

Here is the VBA code (which doesn't work!!)
I am sure it is simple...but not for me.

```
Sub Andy()
'
' Andy Macro
' Andy Update Score
'
'Copy range to clipboard
  Workbooks("Weekly Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Weekly Master").Range("C3:C20").Copy
'PasteSpecial to paste values
 Workbooks("Master Summary 2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Andy").Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy/Paste Values

- At this stage you should avoid using one-liners. Step-by-step is the way to go (BTW We have skipped the step of defining the workbooks).
- `Define` is used instead of *Creating a reference to*.
- s - Source - being copied from.
- d - Destination - being written to.
- It is not entirely clear where to copy, so you might need to adjust the offset to:

  ```
  Offset(0, 1)
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Andy()
'
' Andy Macro
' Andy Update Score
'
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Set sws = Workbooks("Weekly Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Weekly Master")
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range("C3:C20")
    
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = Workbooks("Master Summary 2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Andy")
    ' Define Destination First Cell Range.
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(2, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1)
    
    ' Copy by assignement (more efficient, no selecting, like nothing happened).
    dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    ' If you would have more columns you would have to adjust to:
    'dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Copy with 'PasteSpecial' (in this case not recommended).
    'srg.Copy
    'dCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Using Offset(0, 1) has done the trick.  Thanks for this and answering so quickly.  Just working my way through the logic now as a beginner!!